# How do I get rid of an orphaned default constraint in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I am trying to create a script in order to create a table in SQL Express 2008 R2, like so:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name='Table' AND [type]='U')) BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table
END
GO

CREATE TABLE Table (
    col DATETIMEOFFSET CONSTRAINT DF_Table_col DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
)
GO
```

I am trying to follow the practice of creating a script that can be re-executed for this release cycle of my project.
But the problem is that I forgot to drop the default constraint DF_Table_col before dropping the table "Table", which I would write as:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.default_constraints WHERE name='DF_Table_col')) BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Table DROP CONSTRAINT DF_Table_col
END
GO
```

Now if I try to re-run the script, I get the following error:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
There is already an object named 'DF_Table_col' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

**How do I get rid of the orphaned constraint DF_Table_col?**

I tried to bind this orphan back to a new table by the same name, like so:

```
exec sp_bindefault 'DF_Table_col', 'Table.col'
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
Msg 15050, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_bindefault, Line 108
Cannot bind default 'DF_Table_col'. The default must be created using the CREATE DEFAULT statement.
```

Comment: So, wait. Do you mean that you dropped the table, but somehow the constraint didn't dropped?, this shouldn't happen, I ran your script multiple times with no issues whatsoever. What version of SQL Server are you using?. Are you sure that you don't have **another** table with a constraint named `DF_Table_col`?

Comment: Default names must be unique at the schema level. There's almost certainly some *other* object with that name, not some ghost of the default for the table you dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as DF_Table_col will be deleted if 'Table' is deleted and it belong to 'Table' there might be 'DF_Table_col'. on an other Table.

If you don't care about the name you can use

```
CREATE TABLE Table (
    col DATETIMEOFFSET  DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
)
GO
```